# Android: service not running

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have a service:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.Button;

public class CustTimer extends IntentService {
int length;
long timeLeft;
Button button;
long endTime;

public CustTimer() {
    super("CustTimer");
}

public CustTimer(int length, Button button) {
    super("CustTimer");
    this.length = length;
    this.button = button;
    this.endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + length;


}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
new CountDownTimer(length, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            String min = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/60000 ); 

            long re = millisUntilFinished%60000;
            String secs = String.valueOf(re/1000); 

            button.setText(min + ":" + secs);
            timeLeft = millisUntilFinished;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //button.setText("done");
        }

    }.start();

}
}
```

and an activity which calls it, the onCreate method is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, CustTimer.class);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout l2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout l3 = new LinearLayout(this);
    l3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout l4 = new LinearLayout(this);
    l4.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout l5 = new LinearLayout(this);
    l5.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    LayoutParams hor = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f); 
    LayoutParams ver = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0, 1f);


    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        buts[i] = new Button(this);
        buts[i].setText(String.valueOf(i+1));
        timerRun[i] = false; 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        l2.addView(buts[i], hor);
    }
    for (int i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
        l3.addView(buts[i], hor);
    }
    for (int i = 8; i < 12; i++) {
        l4.addView(buts[i], hor);
    }
    for (int i = 12; i < 16; i++) {
        l5.addView(buts[i], hor);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            final int j = i;
        buts[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CustTimer t1 = new CustTimer(times[j], buts[j]);
                timers[j] = t1;
                startService(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    ll.addView(l2, ver);
    ll.addView(l3, ver);
    ll.addView(l4, ver);
    ll.addView(l5, ver);

    this.setContentView(ll);
}
```

My problem is that the startService() call doesn't return any errors however it wont run. just looking for some basic input on if i've missed anything important to do with services

edit: 
manifest section is:

```
<service android:name="CustTimer"> </service>
```

Comment: Can you post the section of your AndroidManifest.xml that defines your service?

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to implement a simple timer:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO: update button text, manipulate views, etc.

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
};

private void start() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
}

private void stop() {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
}
```

Comment: thanks, my timer is written in a service so that it will continue to run when i temporarily leave the activity and still be running when i return to the activity